# Solving Linear Homogenous recurrence relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

$$g(n)=3n+2^n+4g(n-1)-4g(n-2)$$

Final Solution=homogenous solution + particular solution.

So far I calculated

the homogeneous solution as $A(n) = x 2^n + y 2^n n$

now while solving a particular solution I took $a + bn + 2^n c n^2$

I am not getting any solution for this please help further
also $g(2)=12$ and $g(3)=20$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, but I think there are a fair number of typos remaining which make your question hard to parse. For instance, how does $A$ depend on $h$? More importantly, it's not clear why you're trying to solve this problem, or where you may have gotten stuck. What have you tried? Once we have a better idea of where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor that's the homogenous solution of this recurrence relation

Comment: How can i share my entire solution as a pdf?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes i did that but at last i am not able to compare 2^n from LHS and RHS are the roots are imaginary

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+g%28n%29%3D3n%2B2%5En%2B4g%28n-1%29-4g%28n-2%29%2Cg%282%29%3D12%2Cg%283%29%3D20 This is not able to solve it either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126814/discussion-between-desmond9989-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general solution that $g(n)=(x+yn)2^n$ is correct

Solve $f(n)-4f(n-1)+4f(n-2)=3n$, taking $f(n)=(an+b)$ to get $an+b-4a=3n \implies a=3, b=12.$

Next solve $h(n)=(un^2+vn+w) 2^n$ in $h(n)-4h(n-1)+4h(n-2)=2^n$, to get $u2^{n+1}=2^n \implies u=1/2.$

So the total solution of $$G(n)-4G(n-1)+4G(n-2)=3n+2^n~~~(*)$$ is given as
$$G(n)=(x+yn)2^n+(3n+12)+n^2 2^{n-1}~~~(**)$$
The conditions $G(2)=12, G(3)=20$ give us $x+2y==7/2, x+3y=-37/8$, we get $x=-5/4, y=-9/8.$ Putting these values in (**), we get the final solution of (*).